# Standardization of LASSO Regression

Tags: regression, regularization, lasso

currently I am using the lasso regression to identify a energy function. So there is an input which is lets say **x** and I am creating a library of nonlinear functions of **x**. Those functions should describe the energy function. But the energy is not available. So what I use for the error calculation is d energy/dx and the actual value of that with the MSE. Furthermore I used another error term with the inclusion of the 2. derivative.

So my question would now be:
How do I do my standardization for the lasso regression? Or which terms do I have to standardtize (the nonlinear terms of the library or the input x or the corresponding 1. and 2. derivatives of the nonlinear library terms?)?
And do I have to standardtize the values of the error function?

Overall I get good results without standardization but I have read that standardization is nessesary when using regularized regression to account for multicolinearity. Could there be a workaround the reduce the multicolinearity in another way?